# How can I use Cognito OAuth 2.0 to authenticate a API Gateway request without having an app client secret?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm using aws sdk to manage logins and signups on my app and the sdk requires my app client to have no secret key. This is a problem since I intend to use Cognito to authenticate the API gateway. I tried to enable OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow on app client settings, select a scope and give it to the API method, but when I try to save the app client settings I get:

"We were unable to update your App Configuration: client_credentials flow can not be selected if client does not have a client secret. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidOAuthFlowException"

Is there a better way to configure API Gateway with Cognito? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new app client for your API with a secret.

front end client - app client with out secret
Backend client / api -  app client with secret

Client credentials is a usually a method for service-service authentication. You have to store the secret securely.therefore insecure to use in an unsafe front end app such as an html website.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if I use the app client without secret to login and use the app client with secret to authenticate API calls, how would that work? Wouldn't I need to get an access token generated by the app client with secret for the API to be authenticated?

Comment: Sorry, I answered about how client_credentials work. For the client_credentials to work, you should have a secret.  But you cannot use a secret on a html website. which means you cannot use client_credentials method on the front end .

Comment: For the html client, you should have a client with no secret and using the `implicit grant` method. when you send the request to the api end point, send the `access_token` if your api method is validating against any custom scopes, otherwise send the `id_token`.

Comment: you don't need any to use `client_credentials` unless you have a need to configure inter-service authorization for e.g you need to call another `api` from an existing `api`

Answer (score 0):

To add to Arun's answer, the API should not need a Cognito OAuth client entry and just needs to validate received Cognito access tokens.

Typically this is done by downloading JWKS keys from Cognito - and API Gateway has a setting that automatically does this.

I can provide further details if you run into problems identifying the user after token validation.